# Configuration space calculation with Minkowski inside a 2D polygon

Tags: java, algorithm, polygon, computational-geometry, robotics

I want to calculate the configuration space of a robot **inside** a 2D polygon.
What I know is the following:

If I have a Robot *B* with a reference point *r* attached to *B* and an obstacle *A*, the configuration space of a robot **outside** a 2D polygon can be calculated with the Minkowski Sum.
For this, I calculate *B'* which is a copy of *B* rotated by 180°. Then I use the Minkowski Sum *A+B'* to get the placements of the point *r* where the intersection of *A* and *B* is empty. Or in other words: *B* collides with *A* if *r* intersects *A+B'*. For an example see the image below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTlE9.png

Now I want the configuration space of a robot **inside** a 2D polygon. My first idea was the same way but reverse with the Minkowski Difference *A-B'*. But this doesn't work for a robot which is moving inside the polygon *A*.
So my question is: Can I use the same method here as well including the calculation of the Minkowski Sum (I use for this a decomposing into convex sub-polygons, then a pairwise addition of each corner/vertex, then a calculation of the convex hull and then the union of all "Minkowski-subpolygon-convex-hulls")?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why doesn't minkowski difference work?

Comment: The minkowski difference A-B' is what I get by taking the minkowski sum of a A and the mirror of B'. So, B' gets flipped about the origin again (all of its points are negated). So I have to calculate C := A+B. But when I calculate this, C is a bigger Polygon than A which can't be correct if I want a new Polygon which is inside A. Or do I have a theoretical mistake somewhere?

Comment: If the robot can freely rotate, it seems to me that configuration space inside the polygon is the mink difference of the polygon and an ellipse with the radius of the minimum bounding circle of the robot (aka a buffer inwards).

Comment: Maybe then I get the Minkowski difference wrong? For example, let A: = {(0,0), (2,0), (2,2), (0,2)} and B: = {(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1)} with no rotation and reference point is bottom left (0,0), then A-B = A+B' = {(-1,-1), (2, -1), (2,2), (-1,2)} and B-A = B+A' = {(-2, -2), (1, -2), (1,1), (-2,1)} and A-B' = B-A' = A+B = {(0,0), (3,0), (3,3), (0,3)}. But the solution I want is the configuration space for the reference Point of B, if B is inside A. So I need the Polygon C: = {(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1)}

Answer (score 0):

May be  intersection points of visibile edges can help ... [image]

or just the middle points

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't understand how this can help me when the robot is INSIDE a polygon. In the given problem above I have only one Polygon (or two with the robot). So I don't have these visible edges. Can you explain, how this is supposed to solve my problem.